# How to extract a key from a "search query"?

Tags: java, keyword, text-search

I need to extract the keywords of a search query. For example, suppose one searches for "latest popular Nokia phones". I want to extract the keywords of this phrase. Are there any libraries written in Java to get this done?

Comment: What are the keywords in that search "query"?

Comment: mosNtprobably "Popular and Nokia" would be the keywords.

Comment: Not according to me, and that's why I don't think you'll find a library that can do that. I would say that latest and nokia is more important than popular and nokia. One thing that you could do is write a small program that removes all of the most common words.

Comment: If I was running a search on that phrase I would consider every word to be a "keyword" what criteria are you basing your determination of a keyword on?

Comment: As zacheusz suggested, it looks like the task at hand here is a textual search, not extracting the keywords, in which case you REALLY shouldn't be reinventing the wheel (there's tons of stuff to get wrong, indexing etc.) and use one of the available solutions, most notably, Lucene.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK the [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is doing such a thing (removing words like *a, an, the* and so one). It provides also a Java-based indexing and search implementation, as well as spellchecking, hit highlighting and advanced analysis/tokenization capabilities and much more.

Comment: It does way more than just removing simple words, it's actually way more powerful. Takes some time to dig through the tutorials & docs though, but it gives you really great possibilities.